# Как перебрать все значения 7-bit или 17-бит например

Tags: c#

Есть битовый массив размерности N, `bitarray[любое число в разумных пределах]`.

Как перебрать\сгенерировать все возможные значения и записать их туда-же?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду именно размерность, или всё же размер? (Нет, это не одно и то же.)

Answer (score 3):

Просто пройдитесь в цикле от 0 до 2<sup>N</sup>-1 и переведите каждое число в двоичную систему, это и будут все возможные значения